# Apache Server on Windows 7

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7

I need to install a website in my client's "server" running Windows 7. I know is not a "Server" OS, but:

Will I have any limitation if I install apache HTTPD on this "server", regarding number of conections, etc.? What about PHP_PDO conecting to external SQL Server from this Windows 7 computer? Will I have any kind of limitation because of Windows 7 not being a "Server" OS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win7 is not tuned for server loads, so won't get those extra few percentage points of performance. That said, since as far as Windows is concerned Apache is just a TCP service there are no limitations on concurrent connections beyond what the hardware can support.

As for PHP, that's probably more of a limitation of the Windows PHP_PDO implementation and the ability to load the right SQL drivers on W7. W7 can take regular SQL Client drivers as a host of client-apps leverage just those drivers to query databases, so it can be done.

Comment: The Apache server itself does have COMPILED in maximums for the number of concurrent connections even if the underlying operating system and hardware do not.